# Rig up a Command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

I have a command parameter set on a button as follows:

```
<hw:ActionButton Content="MC" Command="{Binding ActionCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Static hw:Action.MemoryClear}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
```

The command is in the class:

```
public class ActionCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly CalculatorViewModel _viewModel;

    public ActionCommand(CalculatorViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _viewModel != null && parameter is Action;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _viewModel.ProcessAction((Action)parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Now I know commands must be in the ViewModel, so how do I couple this command to the ViewModel? Do I merely have an instance of it in the ViewModel called `ActionCommand`, which doesn't seem to work, or what must I do?

Comment: Your view model will have a public property of type ICommand (perhaps named ActionCommand), which you bind to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a sample for the same

```
class CalculatorViewModel
{
    public CalculatorViewModel()
    {
        ActionCommand = new ActionCommand(this);
        ...
    }

    public ActionCommand ActionCommand { get; private set; }

    ...
}
```

above is a simple sample demonstrating a property for command which can be bound to button in the UI

point to note here is that the binding works only with public properties, public variables does not work in the same way.

as a suggestion you may use some [DelegateCommand](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html) if you are going to create more similar commands.

---

**What is CanExecuteChanged?**

from [Allowing CommandManager to query your ICommand objects](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/06/17/allowing-commandmanager-to-query-your-icommand-objects/)

Because by default WPF has no idea that your custom ICommand objects exist. How would it?

Fortunately there is an easy solution to this problem. In your **ICommand** implementation, you make the **CanExecuteChanged** event hook the ***CommandManager’s RequerySuggested*** event.

sample

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

Comment: But that just gives the view model an `ICommand` property? How do I make the command execute?

Comment: normally this command is bound to a button, menu etc, is executed on click of the bound button. if you see that the button does not get enabled then perhaps you may need to wire `CanExecuteChanged`. see [Allowing CommandManager to query your ICommand objects](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/06/17/allowing-commandmanager-to-query-your-icommand-objects/)for more info

Comment: What I mean is, where is the code that is executed when `ActionCommand` is triggered?

Comment: upon triggering `ActionCommand` the `Execute(object)` method is called from the implementation of `ICommand`. as per your implementation it will eventually call `_viewModel.ProcessAction((Action)parameter);`

Comment: You have no implementation of ICommand in your code, only an ICommand property. What tells that property to execute `Action`?

Comment: my sample code is based on your code where the class `ActionCommand ` implements `ICommand` and does forward the execute method to `_viewModel.ProcessAction`. a view model does not need to implement ICommand.